# Rails Custom Primary Key: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a custom Primary Key (PK), ASIN, in my Products table. This PK is a string.

```
  def change
    create_table :products, id: false do |t|
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.primary_key :asin
      t.string :image
      t.string :price
      t.string :title

      t.timestamps
    end
      change_column :products, :asin, :string
  end
```

In my models for Product, I have the following:

```
  self.primary_key = 'asin'
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :asin
  validates_presence_of :asin, :image, :title, :price, :user_id

  before_save :before_save

  def before_save
    self.asin  = self.asin.upcase!
  end
```

I have looked over the code several times but while trying to hit this Route and create a Product, this is the error I receive.

```
"exception": "#<ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: products.asin>"
```

And this is the JSON that I am sending to this create Route

```
{
    "asin": "B",
    "title": "Test",
    "image": "test",
    "user_id": 1,
    "price": "test"
}
```

**NOTE**: I know that it is generally looked down upon to use PKs in this manor and please know I recognize this but this is the ideal setup for my project's goal. Please refrain from leaving mean-spirited comments.

**EDIT**: For reference, here is the Create function under the Products controller.

```
  skip_before_action :authorize_request, only: [:create, :show]

  def create
    Product.create!(product_params)
    json_response(product_params, :created)
  end

  def product_params
    params.permit(
        :asin,
        :image,
        :title,
        :user_id,
        :price
    )
  end
```

Comment: What's the whole error Rails throws when trying to insert the new record?

Comment: @SebastianPalma Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 92ms (ActiveRecord: 13.1ms | Allocations: 14739)
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: products.asin):
  
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:16:in `create'

Comment: For reference, added an edit that shows the Create function under the Products controller.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Part of the issue was that the asin's first letter needed to be downcased before sending to the backend.

I am not totally sure what happened here to fix this. But I ran the following commands just to test things as I was sure this database setup was perfectly fine.

First, I stopped the server using `control + c` on mac.

I connected to rails using `rails c`
I connected to the products table using `Product.connection`
And I created a test Product just to see what was wrong `Product.create!(asin: "Test_ASIN", title: "title", image: "image", price: "price", user_id: 1)`

I was surprised to see that this worked since this is exactly what I sent to the backend originally, but then I went ahead and started `rails s` and tried to send the request again and this time, it submitted.

I hope this helps someone out there as this was obnoxiously weird.